# Java class and return

Tags: java, class, url, boolean, return

I have a stupid question for you guys, since I get an error with this code.

This is my first Stackoverflow post, so sorry if I did any mistakes.

I want to return a boolean (true or false) by saying this :

```
VerifyClassUnlocked.verify(account.email,account.password,"PRIEST");
```

In another class.

```
package realmclient;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class VerifyClassUnlocked {

    public static boolean verify(String EMAIL, String PASSWORD, String CLASS) {
        URL url;
        InputStream is = null;
        BufferedReader br;
        String line;

        try {
            url = new URL("https://realmofthemadgod.appspot.com/char/list?guid="+EMAIL+"&password="+PASSWORD);
            is = url.openStream();  // throws an IOException
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);

                if (line.contains("<ClassAvailability id=\""+CLASS+"\">unrestricted</ClassAvailability>")){

                    return true;

                }else{

                    return false;                       
                }               
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
             mue.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
             ioe.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (is != null) is.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                // nothing to see here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What error do you get? That should be the first thing you post and first thing you search for.

Comment: Please mention the problem and post an **specific question**.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer guys.

My problem is that this :

public static boolean verify(String EMAIL, String PASSWORD, String CLASS) {

Is not correct.

It says that "it must return a type of boolean".

Comment: What happens if your `while`'s condition returns false on the first run? What is your method supposed to return? What happens if an exception is thrown inside the `try`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that if an exception is thrown, you catch it and then drop to the end of the method without returning a value. What do you want the caller to see at that point?

I suspect you *either* want to let the exception propagate up the stack, *or* you want to move your `return false;` statement to the bottom of the method.

Note that currently if you read *any* line successfully, that's the only line you're going to look at - if it's not the one you were looking for, you immediately return `false`. Is that really what you want to do? It's not clear why you'd have a `while` loop which is only ever going to have a single iteration...

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was a stupid mistake.

Thanks again for the quick and usefull answer. I'll give reputation as soon as I can.